# Can we change or pass bitrate to opus codec during compilation or after compilation for android

Tags: android, linux, android-mediacodec, pjsip, opus

I am working on a audio application, for development of this I am using pjsip . I compiled pjsip with opus but now I want encode audio with different bitrate . Is that possible ? please anyone help me .

Comment: Did you compiled and its working with opus codec ? please guide me how to compile and enable with opus codec in PJSIP library. thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I did it , I compiled pjsip with opus .

Comment: please guide me how to enable opus codec with pjsip.

Comment: when "comipiling ./configure-iphone --with-opus=path-to-opus-dir/"                    it gives...                                                                                              checking opus/opus.h usability... no
checking opus/opus.h presence... no
checking for opus/opus.h... no     ..... where the opus/opus.h file is checking by compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pjsip or opus, but I can say from experience that it is possible to change audio bitrate using Android's MediaCodec. It should just be a matter of decoding the audio stream with one MediaCodec and re-encoding it with another MediaCodec with the newly specified bitrate. If, however, you want to **resample** the audio, you would have to do a lot of extra work by hand between the decode and encode steps provided by MediaCodec. Again, I can tell you from experience that it is possible though.